# How do I add a popup to a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon-sdk

Just like a popup in a Chrome extension. How do I do this in a Firefox extension uising the addon sdk? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html).

The above is probably "not an answer" but I really don't see what else could be added given the question.